# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stock'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to run my python script via shell with the command:

```
        admin@XXXXXX:~$ venv/bin/python3 /volume1/homes/admin/Drive/stock/pri/get_pricetarget.py
```

error I got:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/volume1/homes/admin/Drive/stock/pri/get_pricetarget.py", line 1, in <module>
        import stock as stock
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stock'
```

I have also tried:

```
admin@XXXXXX:~$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) admin@XXXXXX:~$ export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
(venv) admin@XXXXXX:~$ export JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp
(venv) admin@XXXXXX:~$ python3 /volume1/homes/admin/Drive/stock/pri/get_pricetarget.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/volume1/homes/admin/Drive/stock/pri/get_pricetarget.py", line 1, in <module>
    import stock as stock
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stock'
(venv) admin@XXXXXX:~$
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
/stock/
    - __init__.py <empty>
    - stock.py
    - pri/
        - __init__.py <empty>
        - get_pricetarget.py
```

inside stock.py I have:

```
class stock(object):
```

inside get_pricetarget.py I have:

```
import stock as stock
```

I tried running the code in Spyder IDE and it works fine!

```
runfile('//192.168.0.128/home/Drive/stock/pri/get_pricetarget.py', wdir='//192.168.0.128/home/Drive/stock/pri')

Please enter stock code:
```

Comment: Try from .stock import stock

Answer (score -1):

Try this command

```
pip install stock
```

else search for parent library and install the same.

Comment: The OP is trying to import something from a local project, not a pip-installed library